# Qt: Displaying an int in a message box

Tags: c++, qt

I have a timer/clock that displays a message X amounts of seconds (usually 10) after it has been clicked. I attempted to set up an int that one could set easily to change what X is, however I am having trouble with displaying the message, which includes the value of X, in a message box.

What I want:

[image]

Where the value "10" is changed by an int.

The specific line of code for the messagebox:

```
void MainWindow::messageBox(){
QMessageBox::information(this, "Warning!", "You clicked the button of doom " + timerLength/1000 + " seconds ago!");
} //timerLength is an int.
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <qDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);            //Set up timer.
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showtime()));
    //showtime();
    timer->start();
    messageBox();

    otherTimer = new QTimer(this);
    otherTimer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(otherTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(messageBox()));

}

void MainWindow::showtime(){    //Displays current time. Needs to be manually updated.
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    QString lcdText = time.toString("mm:ss");
    ui->lcdNumber->QLCDNumber::display(lcdText);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){

    int timerLength = 10000;
    otherTimer->start(timerLength);
    QPropertyAnimation *progresBar = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->graphicsView, "geometry");
    progresBar->setDuration(timerLength);
    QRect barLocation =ui->graphicsView->geometry();

    progresBar->setStartValue(QRect(barLocation.x(), barLocation.y(), 0, barLocation.height()));
    progresBar->setEndValue(barLocation);

    progresBar->start();
}

void MainWindow::messageBox(){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Warning!", "You clicked the button of doom " + timerLength/1000 + " seconds ago!");
}
```

main.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QLCDNumber>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    int timerLength;

public slots:
    void showtime();
    void messageBox();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer *otherTimer;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Please let me know if more information or explanation is required.

Comment: Try `QString("Warning!", "You clicked the button of doom %1 seconds ago!").arg(timerLength/1000);`

Comment: Like this: `QMessageBox::information(this, "Warning!", QString("You clicked the button of doom %1 seconds ago!").arg(timerLength/1000));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your number to QString like

```
void MainWindow::messageBox(){
QMessageBox::information(this, "Warning!", "You clicked the button of doom " + QString::number(timerLength/1000) + " seconds ago!");
} //timerLength is an int.
```

I tried it works in my app.

Comment: How did you get timerLength to be the same as on_pushButton_clicked? I had to redeclare timerLength in my messagebox, which is something I want to avoid doing.

Comment: I actually did not get what you said however you wanna declare a variable one time, you should declare it in .h file. If you want, you can initialize a value.